# PowerApps - make button not clickable as well as not visible

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm very new to PowerApps and I'd inherited an App which has an component at the bottom of a screen.

In this component are selectable icons but one of which should be only available to the Admins (via a Sharepoint List).

Within the component > Data > Items there is this code:

```
Table(
    {
        Name: "Home",
        Icon: Icon.DetailList,
        Page: Dashboard,        
        Visible:true
    },
    {
        Name: "Bookings",
        Icon: Icon.Person,
        Page: MyAppts,
        Visible:true
    },
    {
        Name: "Book",
        Icon: Icon.Add,
        Page: NewBooking,
        Visible:true
    },
    {
        Name: "Manage",
        Icon: Icon.ComputerDesktop,
        Page: ManageDesks,
        Visible: varAdmin
    }
)
```

The bottom bit hides the icon but is still clickable in the place icon would be showing - how do you disable that as well so it can't be selected?

**Tree View of Component**

[image: Tree View of Component]

**Edit:**
I've tried adding this bit in but still having the same issue.

```
DisplayMode: If(varAdmin, DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)
```

**Found a workaround**

Using this instead for the 'Manage' section - amended the Page to an **If** statement so if part of Admin list then goes to desired screen otherwise stays on same screen. Make sure variable is a Boolean in OnStart.

```
{
        Name: "Manage",
        Icon: Icon.ComputerDesktop,
        Page: If(varAdmin,ManageDesks, Dashboard),
        Visible: varAdmin
    }
```

Comment: Updated your question with a snip of the tree view of your component.